# Oracle SQL: selecting date field without day (Only Month and Year)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to select values from a Database where I have a complete Date. Now I have to get this Date without the Day because I have to group and count them per Month.

I did it like this, but this will get me the Month like for January with 1 and I need 01...

```
(extract(YEAR,Month from ak.date ) || '.' ||extract(Month from ak.date) ) as Datum
```

Comment: How "extract(YEAR, Month from ak.date)" works??!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`TO_CHAR` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm) for this:

```
TO_CHAR(ak.date, 'YYYY.MM') as Datum
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
TRUNC(ak.date, 'MM')
```

Advantage of this is that date sorting and date arithmetic still work.